# Keep triggering an error from is_numeric even though number is numeric

Tags: php

I have a some values that I'm pulling from my database and putting those numbers into text boxes that will be submitted to gather rate quotes. However, on those text boxes I have setup error checking one of which is, is_numeric.

For some reason every time I populate the text box from the DB it triggers this error and I have no idea why.

I have tried:

- Converting the number to an INT
- Converting the number to number_format and then removing the decimals and trailing 0's

I have also tried some other things too but nothing works. Any body have any idea how I can troubleshoot this? I'm out of ideas.

Thanks

Edit:

Everyone wants code but there isn't much to show.

Error checking:

```
        if (!is_numeric($weight)) {
          $errors[] = '<div style="width:780px;" class="alert alert-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></i>&nbsp;Weight must be a number.</div>';
        }
```

Grabbing DB value:

```
       $prod_weight = $row1['weight'];
```

I'm really not sure what else you guys what to see.

Comment: We can't really help you without seeing your code.

Comment: Short answer: It is not numeric. Use `var_dump` on it and show us your code. My guess, without seeing your code, is that PHP only understands `12.34` and not the foreign `12,34` that some countries use, and you're expecting PHP to understand this.

Comment: Additionally, know that `is_numeric` does not allow numbers with thousand seperators. You can strip these off by using `$number = str_replace(',', '', $number)` or strip everything that doesn't belong there off with `$number = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '', $number);`. **Edit** What we want to see is an example of `$weight`. What does `var_dump($weight);` output? And of course the obvious that `$prod_weight` is not the same as `$weight`.

Comment: Let me add that none of these numbers have anything in them besides, well numbers. No decimal, no comma... nothing but numbers. I am completely stumped.

Comment: Did you check if you *actually* use `$weight` and `$prod_weight` and they're not the same?

Comment: @smack-a-bro: Please answer  h2ooooooo's question above. What does `var_dump($prod_weight);` output?

Comment: Var_dump give me this: string(5) "88.00". I'd like to add that I strip the decimal and zeros from this before the textbox ever get a hold of it.

Comment: @smack-a-bro And do you use `if (!is_numeric($weight))` or `if (!is_numeric($prod_weight))`?

Comment: No $weight and $prod_weight are not the same. $weight is for after the form is submitted and $prod_weight is the values that comes from the database.

Comment: @smack-a-bro Then what does `var_dump($weight)` output?

Comment: No, because like my last comment. $prod_weight pretty much becomes $weight after is submitted. 

I take $prod_weight from the DB and I put it into a text box that eventually get submitted. Then upon submission I get this damn error.

Comment: Lastly, If I manually put in a number there I get no errors

Comment: I figured it out, guys. With the help of var_dump. I was seeing that the value had a blank character at the end. I remove that and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Look for blanks spaces in the variables. Var_dump helps.